# Vertical rules in tables are ugly. ChkTex

Tags: chktex

When I run ChkTeX on

```tex
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|}
        \tejastable{\kket{2}}{kket{2}} % \tejastable{\}{} % no need of \\
        \tejastable{2}{3} % automatically goes to next line
        $\ $ & \\
        $\ $ & \\
        $\ $ & \\
        $\ $ & \\
        $\ $ & \\
        $\ $ &
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Special Latex commands used 2}\label{tab:special commands2}
\end{table}
```

I get the following warning

```tex
Warning 44 in main.tex line 40: User Regex: -2:Vertical rules in tables are ugly.
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|}  
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, ChkTeX hates vertical lines (rules) in a table.

> Vertical rules in tables are ugly.

Changing to

```tex
        \begin{tabular}{c c}
```

clears the warning.

Comment: Well, that makes a lot of sense, actually. If you take a look at the numerous questions concerning table layout on this site alone, you will see that the general consensus is that vertical lines in tables do not add any value. On the contrary, they are disturbing the flow of the reader and usually make it harder to interpret tables. It is generally advisable to remove vertical lines from tables whenever possible (which is the large majority of cases).